# Unable to load the Managed C++ dll into C# Dll

Tags: c#

I have a C# application which is built with platform target as ANY CPU. It references a managed C++ application which is built with the platform target as Win32. However the loading of the C++ dll fails at runtime with the following error.  "Could not load file or assembly 'abc_Debug, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Attempt to access invalid address. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800701E7)"

Can anyone give me some pointers as to what could be wrong?

Comment: How are you loading the c++ dll, can you paste the code of loading the dll part?

Comment: It's a very low-level error, something goes wrong when the DLL initializes itself through DllMain().  Enable unmanaged code debugging and cross your fingers that you'll see a first-chance exception in the Output window.

Comment: Well its a managed C++ dll. So I reference it in my C# application directly..Loading if that is failing at runtime..any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general for any loading problem of managed dlls, it's better to use [fuslogvw](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2006/07/12/663834.aspx) it can gives you more details.

Comment: hi there,Thanks all for your responses. I checked the fusion logs and it seems to complain about msvcm80.dll.

Comment: BTW I do have vc redistributable installed FYI

Comment: I used the fuslogv.exe...I see in the default view the loaing of this particular dll is successful. However i see an error in native images , that binding of this dll was not successful..it doesnt give any other info..any thoughts?

Comment: if you find that the loading problem is in the native world, the first step is to use dependecywalker and see if all dependencies needed exist.

Comment: I did check using the dependency walker and it complains of MSVCP80D.dll and MSVCR80.dll missing for some of its depenedent dlls. However MSVCR80.dll is laoded for this dll, but missing for dependant dlls..No clue whats going on..any ideas will help..

Comment: you can test your program in debug mode from viual studio and go to menu Debug->Exceptions and check C++Exceptions and common langage runtime excption.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the application at a x64 architecture then your app is starting as x64 and then it can't load the c++ reference. You cannot build an application as AnyCpu if you don't have all the dependences available for AnyCpu, otherwise set x86 as the target.

Comment: I did set the platform target as x86 and rebuilt it ..it still throws the same exception.

Comment: Wel the release mode works . When i check the dll in dependency walker which has problems in loading it complains about MSVCP80D.dll and MSVCR80D.dll